# php MySQL lastInsertID

Tags: php, mysql

does anybody know why i get return value of 0 with this code:

```
        /* check connection */
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            error_log("Connect failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
            echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"' . mysqli_connect_error() . '"}';
        } else {
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO teams (name, token) VALUES (?, ?)");
            $stmt->bind_param('ss', $team, $token);


            /* execute prepared statement */
            $stmt->execute();

            if ($stmt->error) {error_log("Error: " . $stmt->error); }

            $success = $stmt->affected_rows;

            //Get the last insert ID of the insert Team
            $lastInsertID = $stmt->insert_id;




                //Insert into the Mapping Table
                $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO usersTeamsMap (users_idUser, teams_idTeam) VALUES (?, ?)");
                $stmt->bind_param('ii', $userID , $lastInsertID );


                /* execute prepared statement */
                $stmt->execute();

                //Get the last insert ID of the insert Team
                $lastInsertID = $stmt->insert_id;
                echo "ID: " . $lastInsertID;
```

The last echo always returns 0. The first " $lastInsertID = $stmt->insert_id;" of the first Insert into query works fine.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Thanks for all answers. Now i know why the service didnt work. My mapping table did not have an AutoIncrement field.

Comment: what is first and last? are yu running a loop? where's that part of the code

Comment: Try a `$stmt->close();` after the first one and before you `prepare` the second one.

Answer (score 0):

`insert_id` is an attribute of the mysqli object, not of the statement! It is connection specific.

So it should be `$mysqli->insert_id`.